# HiveServer2: Thrift SASL related exception when using custom PasswdAuthenticationProvider

Tags: hive, thrift, ambari, sasl

I've created a custom implementation of the `PasswdAuthenticationProvider` interface, based on OAuth2. I think the code is irrelevant for the problem I'm experiencing, nevertheless, it can be found [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/cosmos-hive-auth-provider/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cosmos/hive/authprovider/OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl.java).

I've configured `hive-site.xml` with the following properties:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
   <value>CUSTOM</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.custom.authentication.class</name>
   <value>com.telefonica.iot.cosmos.hive.authprovider.OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl</value>
</property>
```

Then I've restarted the Hive service and I've connected a JDBC based remote client with success. This is an example of a successful run found in `/var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log`:

```
2016-02-01 11:52:44,515 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: authprovider.HttpClientFactory (HttpClientFactory.java:<init>(66)) - Setting max total connections (500)
2016-02-01 11:52:44,515 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: authprovider.HttpClientFactory (HttpClientFactory.java:<init>(67)) - Setting default max connections per route (100)
2016-02-01 11:52:44,799 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: authprovider.HttpClientFactory (OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl.java:Authenticate(65)) - Doing request: GET https://account.lab.fiware.org/user?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
2016-02-01 11:52:44,800 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: authprovider.HttpClientFactory (OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl.java:Authenticate(76)) - Response received: {"organizations": [], "displayName": "frb", "roles": [{"name": "provider", "id": "106"}], "app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "email": "frb@tid.es", "id": "frb"}
2016-02-01 11:52:44,801 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: authprovider.HttpClientFactory (OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl.java:Authenticate(104)) - User frb authenticated
2016-02-01 11:52:44,868 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:OpenSession(188)) - Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V6
2016-02-01 11:52:44,871 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(358)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2016-02-01 11:52:44,873 INFO  [pool-5-thread-5]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(358)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
```

The problem is after that the following error appears in a recurrent manner:

```
2016-02-01 11:52:48,227 ERROR [pool-5-thread-4]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(215)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
2016-02-01 11:53:18,323 ERROR [pool-5-thread-5]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(215)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
```

Why? I've seen in several other questions this occurs when using the default value of `hive.server2.authentication`, i.e. `SASL`, and the client is not doing the handshake. But in my case, the value of such a property is `CUSTOM`. I cannot understand it, and any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've found there are periodical requests to the HiveServer2... from the HiveServer2 itself! These are the requests that are resulting in Thrift SASL errors:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo port 10000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
...
...
10:18:48.183469 IP dev-fiwr-bignode-11.hi.inet.ndmp > dev-fiwr-bignode-11.hi.inet.55758: Flags [.], ack 7, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 1034162147 ecr 1034162107], length 0
^C
21 packets captured
42 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[fiware-portal@dev-fiwr-bignode-11 ~]$ sudo netstat -nap | grep 55758
tcp        0      0 10.95.76.91:10000           10.95.76.91:55758           CLOSE_WAIT  7190/java           
tcp        0      0 10.95.76.91:55758           10.95.76.91:10000           FIN_WAIT2   -                   
[fiware-portal@dev-fiwr-bignode-11 ~]$ ps -ef | grep 7190
hive      7190     1  1 10:10 ?        00:00:10 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71//bin/java -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop/hive -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hive -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx1024m -Xmx4096m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-service-0.13.0.2.1.7.0-784.jar org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2 -hiveconf hive.metastore.uris=" " -hiveconf hive.log.file=hiveserver2.log -hiveconf hive.log.dir=/var/log/hive
1011     14158 12305  0 10:19 pts/1    00:00:00 grep 7190
```

Any idea?

**EDIT 2**

More research about the connections sent from HiveServer2 to HiveServer2. Data packets always sent 5 bytes, the following ones (hexadecimal): `22 41 30 30 31`

Any idea about these connections?

Answer (score 0):

I finally "fixed" this. Since the message was sent by the Ambari agent running in the HiveServer2 machine (some king of weird ping), I simply added an `iptables` rule blocking all the connections to TCP/10000 port on the loopback interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DROP
```

Of course, now Ambari warns the HiveServer2 is not alive (the pings are droped). And the above rule must be removed if I want to restart the server from Ambari (there is another alive check in the starting script); then after the restart I can enable the rule again. Well, I can live with that.